# Upload 3 photo in php

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, photo

I'm having trouble uploading photos for my TP. I have my first picture that goes well s'upload but the second and third nothing at all. I put a raw image in the database and then I went back to the site to test in upload it removes me well my image link but I do not have the new ones that come to replace it and no image on the server.

Here is my code:

```
$image = "";$image_2 = "";
$image_3 = "";
 
if(isset($_FILES['pointpicture']) AND !empty($_FILES['pointpicture']['name']))
{
    $taillemax = 2097152;
    $extensionvalides = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
     
    if($_FILES['pointpicture']['size'] <= $taillemax)
    {
        $extensionupload = strtolower( substr(strrchr($_FILES['pointpicture']['name'],'.'),1));
         
        if(in_array($extensionupload,$extensionvalides))
        {
            $img = RandomString();
            $chemin = $abs_path."images/pointpictures/".$img.".".$extensionupload;
            $image = "images/pointpictures/".$img.".".$extensionupload;
            $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pointpicture"]["tmp_name"], $chemin);
             
            if($resultat)
            {
                //select current user old profile picture name
                $avatar = $mysqli->query("SELECT image FROM pointsofinterest WHERE id = ".$pointid )->fetch_object()->image;
                $filename = $abs_path."images/pointpictures/".$avatar;
                if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    unlink($filename);
                }
                system('chmod 775 "'.$chemin.'"');
            }
            else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=uploaderror'); }
        } else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=badformat'); }
         
    } else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=picistofat'); }
}
else
{
    $image = $mysqli->query("SELECT image FROM pointsofinterest WHERE id = '".$pointid."'")->fetch_object()->image;
}
 
if(isset($_FILES['pointpicture2']) AND !empty($_FILES['pointpicture2']['name']))
{
    $taillemax = 2097152;
    $extensionvalides = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
     
    if($_FILES['pointpicture2']['size'] <= $taillemax)
    {
        $extensionupload = strtolower( substr(strrchr($_FILES['pointpicture2']['name'],'.'),1));
         
        if(in_array($extensionupload,$extensionvalides))
        {
            $img = RandomString();
            $chemin = $abs_path."images/pointpictures/".$img.".".$extensionupload;
            $image_2 = "images/pointpictures/".$img.".".$extensionupload;
            $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pointpicture2"]["tmp_name"], $chemin);
             
            if($resultat)
            {
                //select current user old profile picture name
                $avatar = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_2 FROM pointsofinterest WHERE id = ".$pointid )->fetch_object()->image;
                $filename = $abs_path."images/pointpictures/".$avatar;
                if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    unlink($filename);
                }
                system('chmod 775 "'.$chemin.'"');
            }
            else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=uploaderror'); }
        } else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=badformat'); }
         
    } else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=picistofat'); }
}
else
{
    $image_2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_2 FROM pointsofinterest WHERE id = '".$pointid."'")->fetch_object()->image;
}
 
if(isset($_FILES['pointpicture3']) AND !empty($_FILES['pointpicture3']['name']))
{
    $taillemax = 2097152;
    $extensionvalides = array('jpg','jpeg','png');
     
    if($_FILES['pointpicture3']['size'] <= $taillemax)
    {
        $extensionupload = strtolower( substr(strrchr($_FILES['pointpicture3']['name'],'.'),1));
         
        if(in_array($extensionupload,$extensionvalides))
        {
            $img = RandomString();
            $chemin = $abs_path."images/pointpictures/".$img.".".$extensionupload;
            $image_3 = "images/pointpictures/".$img.".".$extensionupload;
            $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pointpicture3"]["tmp_name"], $chemin);
             
            if($resultat)
            {
                //select current user old profile picture name
                $avatar = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_3 FROM pointsofinterest WHERE id = ".$pointid )->fetch_object()->image;
                $filename = $abs_path."images/pointpictures/".$avatar;
                if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    unlink($filename);
                }
                system('chmod 775 "'.$chemin.'"');
            }
            else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=uploaderror'); }
        } else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=badformat'); }
         
    } else { header('Location: '.$base_url.'mespoints?modif=picistofat'); }
}
else
{
    $image_3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT image_3 FROM pointsofinterest WHERE id = '".$pointid."'")->fetch_object()->image;
}
 
$requete = "UPDATE pointsofinterest SET categorie = '".$pointcat."', titre = '".$pointname."', address = '".$pointaddress."', tel = '".$pointphone."',
            longitude = '".$pointlong."', latitude = '".$pointlat."', keywords = '".$pointkeywords."', email = '".$pointemail."', website = '".$pointwebsite."',
            description = '".$pointdesc."', facility = '".$pointfacility."', facebook = '".$pointfacebook."', instagram = '".$pointinstagram."', twitter = '".$pointtwitter."',
            horairesLundi = '".$pointhoraireslundi."', horairesMardi = '".$pointhorairesmardi."', horairesMercredi = '".$pointhorairesmercredi."',
            horairesJeudi = '".$pointhorairesjeudi."', horairesVendredi = '".$pointhorairesvendredi."', horairesSamedi = '".$pointhorairessamedi."',
            horairesDimanche = '".$pointhorairesdimanche."', image = '".$image."', image_2 = '".$image_2."', image_3 = '".$image_3."' WHERE id = '".$pointid."'";
 
mysqli_query($mysqli, $requete);
```

Comment: can you paste your HTML code ?

Comment: <form class="fuzone">                                                                                                                                                        <input type="file" id="pointpicture2" name="pointpicture2" class="upload">
</form>

Comment: that's your full HTML code ?

Comment: It's for the image two for the picture one replaces pointpicture2 by pointpicture and for the picture three by pointpicture3

Comment: if i understand you have something like : 

`<form class="fuzone"> <input type="file" id="pointpicture" name="pointpicture" class="upload"> </form>

<form class="fuzone"> <input type="file" id="pointpicture2" name="pointpicture2" class="upload"> </form>

<form class="fuzone"> <input type="file" id="pointpicture3" name="pointpicture3" class="upload"> </form>
`

Comment: Almost that because it misses a little but as for the photos that's it. I do not have the computer with me

Comment: In fact if it like this you make a little error. For upload 3 images you does to put your 3 inputs field in the same form tags

Comment: It's really voluntary on my part these are different things, because there is not all the html

Answer (score 1):

add `[]` as a name of your field

```
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
```